# How to fix ACPI / thermal errors on Dell Inspiron 5770 running Debian sid?

Tags: debian, boot, cpu, acpi, temperature

I have a Dell Inspiron 5770 that is running Debian unstable (sid). I get the following errors upon boot:

```
[    0.048160] ACPI Error: [_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PXSX] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/dswload2-191)
[    0.048166] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20170831/psobject-252)
[    0.048168] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.RP04.PXSX, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psparse-550)
[    0.048374] ACPI Error: [_SB_.PCI0.RP09.PXSX] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/dswload2-191)
[    0.048377] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20170831/psobject-252)
[    0.048379] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.RP08.PXSX, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psparse-550)
[    0.049193] ACPI: Executed 54 blocks of module-level executable AML code
[    0.056785] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
```

and

```
[    9.955872] CPU5: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[    9.955873] CPU1: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[    9.955874] CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[    9.955875] CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[    9.955877] CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[    9.955934] CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[    9.955935] CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[    9.955935] CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[    9.955936] CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[    9.956045] CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
[    9.956872] CPU5: Core temperature/speed normal
[    9.956873] CPU1: Core temperature/speed normal
[    9.956873] CPU5: Package temperature/speed normal
[    9.956874] CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
[    9.956951] CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
[    9.956952] CPU6: Package temperature/speed normal
[    9.956953] CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
[    9.956953] CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
[    9.956954] CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
[    9.956955] CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
```

I'm worried about the temperature warnings, because I don't want to damage the CPU if something isn't working properly with thermal regulation. I came back home today, and am pretty sure my computer shut itself down due to overheating while I was gone.

**This is a brand new computer, so it's not happening because of dust.**

I have checked the BIOS settings, and there is nothing that seems to be disabled regarding ACPI/thermal. Is there something I might need to install or configure to make temperature control work properly? Do I need to worry about these messages?

Comment: Clean your computer inside.

Comment: It's a brand new computer. That's not the issue.

Comment: Most likely these can be ignored. I would still google each message, but most likely this is a fallout from the mess in ACPI related kernel development, where the right hand does not know what the left is doing, lack of coordination, lack of development aptitude and blatant lack of will to cooperate on the part of both kernel devs and HW manufacturers. I've been raising bug reports re ACPI for decades and most of them were ignored or closed for made up reasons in both distro and kernel trackers. YMMV.

Comment: Thanks. I would feel fine ignoring the ACPI messages if they weren't accompanied by the CPU temperature warnings, and the fact that my computer seems to have shutdown from overheating. Do you think the ACPI messages are unrelated? What should I do about the temperature warnings? I don't want to just ignore them and damage my hardware.

Comment: Have you tried installing the `thermald` package?

Comment: @Vlastimil - I did not have `thermald` installed. I went ahead and installed it, and the message did not appear upon boot this time. However, it wasn't appearing every time before either, so I'll have to see if it pops up again ... But it tentatively looks like it might have solved the overheating issue. Still having same ACPI errors pop up though. Anyways, thanks! The CPU temp part was definitely the more concerning one for me... Why would thermald not be installed by default, if it's necessary to prevent hardware damage?

Answer (score 2):

Concerning the warning:

> ```
> Package temperature above threshold...
> ```

Yes, you need to worry about this warning.

The [thermald](https://wiki.debian.org/thermald) package might be worth trying as it monitors various temperatures and adjusts where necessary.

Quoting the wiki:

> Once the system temperature reaches a certain threshold, the Linux daemon activates various cooling methods to try to cool the system.

and

> Zero Configuration Mode
>    For most users, this should be enough to bring the CPU temperature of the system under control.

Just installing the package should be enough, no need to configure it in most cases.

In other cases, you may wish to edit the XML config file:

```
/etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml
```

The [Ubuntu man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/thermal-conf.xml.5.html) contains basic information.

---

Concerning the ACPI errors starting with:

> ```
> ACPI Error: [_SB_.PCI0.RP05.PXSX] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/dswload2-191)
> ```

There may be two separate ways to resolve them, but I don't find them related to your CPU thermal issue, so it's probably not so important.

First, upgrade your BIOS. I described the procedure on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/818386/how-to-upgrade-bios-on-dell-poweredge-t20-server/818387#818387). Be sure to be connected to a UPS, throughout the procedure.

Afterwards, you may try installing `intel-microcode` package, it resolves many current issues.

---

And just another suggestion would be now to monitor your CPU temperature with:

```
sudo i7z
```

If you do not have `i7z` installed, just install it. The package name as far as I remember is the same, i.e. `i7z`.

Comment: After installing `thermald`, the message didn't initially appear after reboot, which got my hopes up. But unfortunately, I was just doing some CPU intensive GIS work and it popped up again :( ... I'll play around with thermald config and see if I need to do something else.